# SmartFoxServer 2x using sfsApi, NullPointerException

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

I am simply trying to set a room variable (adding the user's name to a room varible) in my UserJoinedRoomHandler:
From my JAVA extension:

```
public class UserJoinedRoomHandler extends BaseServerEventHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handleServerEvent(ISFSEvent arg0) throws SFSException
    {
        User user = (User) arg0.getParameter(SFSEventParam.USER);
        Room room = (Room) arg0.getParameter(SFSEventParam.ROOM);
        trace("add p1 = " + user.getName() + " to room=" + room.getId());
        List<RoomVariable> listOfVars = new ArrayList<RoomVariable>();
        listOfVars.add( new SFSRoomVariable("player1Name", user.getName()) );
        ((MyExtension) getParentExtension()).sfsApi.setRoomVariables(user, room, listOfVars);   // NullPointerException here :(
    }
}
```

Note, I grab the sfsAPI when in MyExtention init() function:

```
ISFSApi sfsApi = SmartFoxServer.getInstance().getAPIManager().getSFSApi();
```

To me this should work, the only thing I can think of is that the room might not have fully initialised (the user had just created the room before this event is fired). But in any case I thought this should be a trivial scenario, but it has cost me a good handful of hours already.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: So what is the nullpointer about? Can you post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the Api directly:

((MyExtension) getParentExtension()).getApi().setRoomVariables(user, room, listOfVars);

PS: Unfortunately there is no method to issue 1 Room Variable. You have to submit a list, even if its only 1 in length.